# Flagging Posts and Comments as Spam

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, spam, posts

I was reviewing a question and came across this, before it was revised:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17500917/revisions

I flagged it as spam, as it seemed to be a plug for that person's business. The flag was knocked back, and as you can see the question was edited.

What is the best way to manage posts like this?

Another example is the following comment:

> I will shamelessly plug my not-free #########. – ########

[get user country code in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501238/get-user-country-code-in-php)

Is it appropriate to flag such a comment as spam?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *[blah blah blah useful code]*
>
> *$NAME*, software engineer, *$COMPANY*.

In my judgement, spam has *no* useful content and can *never* be salvaged. That's not spam there, that's a little bit of self-promotion and some useful stuff. Edit out the self-promotion and the answer is fine. That, IMO, is the right side of the thin spam-coloured line. (Leave a warning comment if you want to; I've done that sometimes in the First Posts and Late Answers queues on SO.)

> I will shamelessly plug my not-free *$PRODUCT*.

That, IMO, is *perfectly* within the bounds of the self-promotion policy. It's (as far as I can tell) relevant to the question, and (based on a random sampling of nine of the user's answers {[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465582/php-converting-an-array-in-string/17465827#17465827), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486906/how-to-select-characters-before-in-emails-for-php/17486963#17486963), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367653/caching-html-in-variables/17368005#17368005), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463674/embedded-adaptive-payments-for-digital-goods-between-2-users-confused-about-th/17463993#17463993), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493608/object-method-call-vs-class-method-call-best-practice/17493725#17493725), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166124/how-to-add-a-non-existent-method-name-to-suggest-list-under-zend-studio/17166255#17166255), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151452/extract-content-from-url-and-website/17151711#17151711), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137029/how-to-get-returned-data-from-constructor/17137605#17137605), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201342/php-destruct-called-twice/17101813#17101813)}) is an isolated incident - far removed from some of the stuff I see in the review queues (which also contained hardly anything else, and weren't worthy of being answers).

This **comment** wasn't trying to masquerade as an answer, and was relevant to the topic at hand, *and* was not part of a pattern ([see for yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451110/codeangry?tab=activity&sort=comments)). No problem here.

Comment: thnx Michael, I need to read up on the self promotion policy

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not outright spam. That is, it seems to contain an actual answer (the quality of which is up to discussion) and some unnecessary spammy content. You can flag it, but I would personally just edit it. Remove the offending content and job done.

If the user is someone who does that on every post, a custom flag might be in order. Just notify a moderator that this seems to be the MO of the user and perhaps he can leave a comment asking the user to stop it. Or you can leave a comment like that yourself if you're so inclined, but seeing a mod diamond carries a bit more weight. (And I went ahead and [left a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023756/how-to-add-css-class-in-aspx-cs-page-means-code-behind-page/17501016#comment25441731_17501016).)

As for the comment, I would have left that one alone. It's a comment, not an answer. But you are free to flag that one, and I'm sure there are users who will. Once again though, if the user seems to have a history of leaving many such comments (i.e. this is not an occasional occurrence) a flag might be in order.

Comment: thnx Bart, I had difficulty in marking one as answer, as they are both good.

Comment: @Yve In that case you should always select mine. I'll ask for a Help Center update to clearly state so. ;)

Comment: oops, was that a joke?? cos I changed my answered, it's the 31.8k, it carries weight ! lol

Comment: Hahahahaha, yes, that was a joke. Feel free to change it back. Whatever you accept is up to you. The rep I have is based on the amount of time I wasted. It carries no more weight than that. ;)

Comment: I like that Bart, yes, yes, I go and cruise the questions, when I am supposed to be studying! I justify it as a constructive waste of time ;)... and I hope I haven't broken some rule by changing the as answered so quickly hahahha

Answer (score 1):

As the moderator who declined the flag I'll elaborate on my reasoning and observations as I handled the flag:

1. There is useful content in the post - it seems to be a good faith attempt to answer the question
2. The link and text looks like a signature. The answer works equally well without it. *This is a common issue for new users, but it's something the community can handle*. (As Sirko did, or you could have suggested an edit).
3. There may be an issue with other posts and a bigger pattern, but flagging it "spam" alone doesn't capture that information and misrepresented the intentions.

If editing is appropriate go ahead and do that. Generally after editing a few times new users get the hint. If they don't get the hint (you can use comments too if needed) then flag to escalate, but use a custom flag to explain more precisely what the issue is.

Generally the spam flag is appropriate for "buy nike handbags" style of spam, affiliate link schemes, astroturfing (although again for that a custom flag is probably more helpful if you can cite evidence).

I don't think it's appropriate to use spam flags for "good faith" answer attempts. Reserve it for "open and shut" cases of 100% pure spam.

Comment: thnx Flexo, just so you know -  I wasn't complaining that you declined it,  just want clarity of how to proceed, which I have in spades now ! when you say a custom flag, that is the "other" where comments are put , yes?

Comment: ps I already marked an answer as answered and Bart is standing over me for the answered question bonus ;) LOL - so I can only give the upvote

Comment: @Yve yep, "custom flag" = other, uses a free text field in the UI. (I'm not worried about rep on MSO)

Comment: That was just a poor attempt at humor. Yep, I am trying to keep my flags, comments and edits as useful as possible, and review my progress, to improve it.. how ridiculously pedantic is that?? there is no help for me.. mind you, it beats facebook :)

Comment: *Anyone trying to sell us handbags clearly has their finger firmly on the pulse of SO. It is what we crave.* -Shog9 (I think)